# I can't use Ionic position in a controller in Ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hy guys !

I'm trying to develop a mobile app who take my phone gps position, send it to a json webservices in parameters to get back search results. In my code i successfully get positioN but In `this.http.get(url)` my controller doesn't see url give by my function, I don't understand why?

Thanks for your help

```
export class HomePage {

public items:any;
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public http: Http) {

var url="";
var latitude ="";
var longitude ="";
var onSuccessposition = function(position) {        
    latitude = position.coords.latitude ;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude ;
    url = "http://www.myurl.com/recherche_json.php?latitude_utilisateur="+latitude+"&longitude_utilisateur="+longitude;
    alert(url);
    return url  
  };    

  var onErrorposition = function(error) {
    alert('ACTIVEZ VOTRE GEOLOCALISATION !!!');
    return false;
  }       

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccessposition, onErrorposition);

  this.http = http;
    this.http.get(url)
        .subscribe(data =>{
          //console.log(data['_body']);
         this.items=JSON.parse(data['_body']).results;//Bind data to items **strong text**object
        },error=>{
            console.log(error);// Error getting the data
        } );
}
```

Comment: instead of defining url in constructor initialize it before public items:any;

Comment: thank you guy for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
public items:any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public http: Http) {

    Splashscreen.show();
  Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {

   var latitude = resp.coords.latitude;
   var longitude = resp.coords.longitude;
var url = "http://www.chantiermoinscher.com/jasoif/recherche_json.php?latitude_utilisateur="+latitude+"&longitude_utilisateur="+longitude;

  this.http = http;
    this.http.get(url)
        .subscribe(data =>{
          //console.log(data['_body']);
         this.items=JSON.parse(data['_body']).results;//Bind data to items object
        },error=>{
            console.log(error);// Error getting the data
        } );

        Splashscreen.hide();
      });       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would declare the url outside of the constructor:

```
export class HomePage {

public items:any;
url : String = "";

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public http: Http) {


var latitude ="";
var longitude ="";
var onSuccessposition = function(position) {        
    latitude = position.coords.latitude ;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude ;
    this.url = "http://www.myurl.com/recherche_json.php?latitude_utilisateur="+latitude+"&longitude_utilisateur="+longitude;
    alert(this.url);
    return this.url  
  };    

  var onErrorposition = function(error) {
    alert('ACTIVEZ VOTRE GEOLOCALISATION !!!');
    return false;
  }       

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccessposition, onErrorposition);

    this.http = http;
    this.http.get(this.url)
        .subscribe(data =>{
          //console.log(data['_body']);
         this.items=JSON.parse(data['_body']).results;//Bind data to items **strong text**object
        },error=>{
            console.log(error);// Error getting the data
        } );
}
```